# How do we calculate the current through two impedances in series by knowing the voltage of one and the impedance of the other?

Tags: current, impedance, three-phase, apparent-power

I have a problem where I know the apparent power consumed by a Y-connected load and the line impedances, which I already reduced to work just with the line power (300kVA): the source and two impedances in series. I know the impedance of the line (ZL) (2.5+j10.2) and the voltage drop across Van (2000V).

It sounds simple, however, I am stuck on how I can know the current. Is it valid to assume that if I know the voltage through Zan and the impedance ZL, I can calculate the current I2 flowing through Z2 using simply I2​=VZ2/​Z​1​? Once I have the current, I can find VL and the voltage emitted by the source.

Do you know where I can learn/read about it?

I attached a diagram of the circuit:

[image]

Comment: Show us a diagram with the quantities labeled so we know what you're referring to.